# Creating JS library Warning instead of Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla

I am creating my own JS library with NPM. I want to give the users of my library a warning but not an error, *however*, I want my users to have a stacktrace of the warning that I log inside my library. So to get the stacktrace, I use new Error().stack. The problem with this is (1) the word 'Error' appears in the stacktrace by default and (2) the stack trace is the same for Node and Chrome but different for Mozilla.

So my question is - what is the best way to create a warning message that has a stacktrace, but that doesn't look like an error? Chrome and Node.js are aligned and I could simply remove the first element of the stack array before calling toString() on it. But the problem is that this wouldn't work for Mozilla.

Anyway, this is what I currently do in my library when there should be a warning emitted:

```
 var err = new Error('looks like you have called IdempotentJSON.parse on an object that was already parsed');
 console.error(err.message.concat('\n'),err.stack);
```

this "logs a warning" that looks like this

*in Chrome*

```
 looks like you have called IdempotentJSON.parse on an object that was already parsed
 Error: looks like you have called IdempotentJSON.parse on an object that was already parsed
    at IdempotentJSON.parse (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/idempotent-json.js:11:23)
    at Backbone.Model.extend.persistModel.save.success (http://localhost:3000/static/app/js/models/userModel.js:88:56)
    at Object._.extend.save.options.success (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/backbone.js:620:30)
    at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:3099:30)
    at Object.jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:3211:7)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:8264:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:8605:9)
```

*in Mozilla Firefox:*

```
"looks like you have called IdempotentJSON.parse on an object that was already parsed
" "IdempotentJSON.prototype.parse@http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/idempotent-json.js:11:23
@http://localhost:3000/static/app/js/app.js:157:30
Backbone.batchSyncCollection/<@http://localhost:3000/static/app/js/app.js:141:16
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:3099:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:3211:7
done@http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:8264:5
.send/callback/<@http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:8605:1
```

*in Node.js*

```
looks like you have called IdempotentJSON.parse on an object that was already parsed
 Error: looks like you have called IdempotentJSON.parse on an object that was already parsed
    at IdempotentJSON.parse (/Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/first_comcast/node_modules/idempotent-json/index.js:9:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/first_comcast/IJSONexp/ijson.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

one quick solution that would work for Node.js and Chrome would be to remove the first line of the stack trace that says "Error:...".

But this call is not valid:

```
err.stack.shift(); //error
```

apparently the stack is not an Array in JS?

And this wouldn't work for Mozilla anyway.

Is my best bet another library that checks which environment/browser that it's in? Like this:

http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/

it's 2015! By the way Mozilla, Chrome and Node have it right with the stack trace, I can click on the stack trace in Chrome and Node and it takes me to the files involved, doesn't seem like I can do this in Firefox.

What I want is something that looks like this:

```
 Warning: looks like you have called IdempotentJSON.parse on an object that was already parsed
    at IdempotentJSON.parse (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/idempotent-json.js:11:23)
    at Backbone.Model.extend.persistModel.save.success (http://localhost:3000/static/app/js/models/userModel.js:88:56)
    at Object._.extend.save.options.success (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/backbone.js:620:30)
    at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:3099:30)
    at Object.jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:3211:7)
    at done (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:8264:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback (http://localhost:3000/static/vendor/jquery.js:8605:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the source of [`console.trace`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L94-L102) you can try this for chrome & node.js:

```
function warning(message) {
  var err = new Error;
  err.name = 'Warning';
  err.message = message; //or use util.format in nodejs
  Error.captureStackTrace(err, warning); // this is to prevent `warning` function being included in the stack.
  return err;
};
console.log(warning('message').stack);
```

In nodejs, this outputs:

```
Warning: message
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/warning.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Unfortunately firefox doesn't have [`captureStackTrace`](https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi#Stack_trace_collection_for_custom_exceptions) method. So you have to call the above directly without wrapping it in a function.